How do I realistically write flight as a skill for an elemental Conjurer's ability, without making it seem too cheesy
In my world, Conjurers are a set of individuals with the ability to call on a Force Of Nature and wield it's powers, few extremely powerful Conjurers can wield more than one Force at a time, but the cost for tasking the Forces for too long or abusively results in asphyxiation. As a Conjurer with Wind-Force abilities, how do I realistically write flight as a skill in and out of battle sequences without being cheesy

You...just did? What other explanation than "Conjurers can call the wind force" do you need?

Also, I don't get the "without being cheesy" thing.

This could be a fun question, but as is, needs work. What do you mean specifically as too cheesy? I like WH40K, and it has Italian cuisine levels of cheese.

Like I mean without seeming too unrealistic, originally I'd imagined them to move like the witches in His Dark Materials, but then again, I wouldn't want them to be too OP as regards to battle

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. We're happy to help you develop the rules governing conjuring in your world, but per the [help/on-topic], we do not help people write stories. The problem is that there's no right answer when it comes to writing style (and you're already seeing that with the spread of answers you're getting, opinion-based). This question is likely off-topic even at [writing.se]. Stack Exchange is not designed to take the place of an education. You need to take a creative writing class.

What is your exact concern with it coming off as cheezy?  As long as you can manipulate air hard enough, then you can create all the reaction force that you need to fly making it one of the more plausible applications of magic I can think of.

Cheesy is in the eye of the beholder
Imagine being in the early medieval period and writing a fantasy book. You'll include modern guns. Initially you'll feel they are cheesy. A single person could mow down hundreds, maybe thousands of men! Give everyone one and people would not even want to fight. You could die kilometers away from gunfire without warning. They'll easily apply their own perspectives of battle and include guns. In real life guns create a radically different battlefield, where all tactics are different. From positioning to how reinforcements are deployed. It can still be epic, though you need to convince your reader.
This applies to your flight as well. It'll very much change the landscape, though because it exists the battles will change accordingly. It can vbe very simple though. Hude under a tree so you can't be seen, but you see the flying person. A flying person is also relatively easy to spot, do an easy target. If you write well about the advantages and disadvantages you will create a world that makes sense. Flying people willl not instantly rule the world. They have great potential power mostly in mobility, getting better angles on the enemy. It is by no means an unbeatable strategy.
The same is true outside of combat. As an example you can state privacy. You can walk up to some houses and look inside. It actually happening is rare. Flight would give you the opportunity to see and hear things you might not be privy to, but common decency prevents you from flying close to houses or flats. Enter your flat via the front door and not your balcony! Especially with the relatively few that can fly and are probably easily recognised. This way you can regulate and 'control' flight in your book without any cheesy strategies.

Very high concentration requirement
This answer is very opinion based, but if you want to limit the use of flight skills in battles, just make it difficult to use, e.g. define that the conjurer requires quite a lot and permanent concentration to stay in the air.

It may be easy enough to fly in a controlled environment but could be too dificult while you have to watch out for other things (e.g. evade incoming fire balls)
The conjurer may not be able to do much else while flying (or risk asphyxiation), which makes flying in battle quite useless
The flight skill may be usable in battles mostly to bring you to a better position but not for much more

You can tailor this up or down to a level where you feel comfortable, from

they can fly but do only weak or simple attacks at the same time

to

they fall out of the sky as soon as you startle them

This may depend on the experience of the conjurer.

Flying is Dangerous. Especially in combat situations.
Naval aviators (the pilots that land on aircraft carriers) have the highest mortality rates of all servicemen (including infantry). Your conjurers will know that keeping both feet planted on the ground will always hive them better odds in battle.
Flying above the tree line has no cover, and below it is extremely difficult. The notable exceptions are for drastic situations that require a quick retreat or a covert insertion. Jumping into the air above a battlefield is a sure way to make yourself a target and get shot down.
